# Row selection and putting border using VBA macros in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I Need to find the non empty rows in a sheet from row 13 and put a top thick border to the selected non empty rows till the last used rows of the sheet. from the column C i need to find the non empty row. I tried this code but it is not working. can u plz help me out

```
Sub rowfind3()
Dim cell As Range
Dim r1 As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
        Set r1 = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AV" & ActiveCell.Row)
        r1.Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If


Next cell

End Sub
```

In this code only the first row the border is displayed, however for the successive rows the border is not coming.

Also i tried another code for the above scenario, but the same first row is only the border is displayed.

```
Sub rowfind1()
'
' rowfind Macro
'

'
Dim r1 As Range
Dim lr As Variant
Dim i As Integer


lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
i = 0

For i = 13 To lr - 11

If (Not (IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3).Value))) Then


   Set r1 = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AV" & ActiveCell.Row)
    r1.Select

    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, no need to use selection. All that ends up doing is potentially confusing the code (as in this case). Secondly, theres no need to re-declare the range inside the loop. Thats what the loop is there for.

Here is how it should look:

```
Sub rowfind3()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
    With cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I would look at changing the Activesheet to reference the actual sheet you want it on and only look at the UsedRange as well to speed it up a bit, but that code will now at least get you there.

---

Addendum based on Comments clarification:

```
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Range("C13:C" & lr)
    With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but i need to put border for the entire row and not for elected cell. so i need to ser the range of teh active row, then should apply formatting right.

Comment: In that case the code in your question is irrelevant as both do a cell at a time. if I now understand you correctly, you need just the outer border of all cells in column c?

Comment: Sorry, outer border of all cells AFTER Row 13 in column C

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use Conditional Formatting? For example on Columns `$A:$AV` formula is      `=$A1<>""`, in formatting choose borders.